# How do I save the state of my activity

Tags: android, android-activity, save, state

How do I save the way my Activity is so when closed with the back button and resumed it will be the same way it was when closed.

this is my Activity code:

public class Levels extends Activity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    setContentView(R.layout.levels);

    final EditText anstext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.anstext1);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
             String result = anstext1.getText().toString();
             if(result.equals("they"))
                 setContentView(R.layout.social);
             else 
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    }
```

}

Comment: Searching helps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android (duplicate)

Comment: "resume" means after the app closes and restarts?

Answer (score 1):

In the `onSaveInstanceState()` method you can add your data into the bundle and then when the `onCreate()` is called you can grab those previous values from the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Use [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) like explained here

Answer (score -1):

You can use `onResume` to restore the resources, and when Activity is dead, you can use properties to save resources and roll back.